# How to save images from Multi Image Picker keeping it's original metadata/exif content in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, image-processing

The package returns an `Asset` object from witch I can extract the `metadata/exif` and `byteData` from the image, but I'm having a hard time finding a way to write a new file that contains the image with it's original `metadata/exif` content.

Here's what I already tried:

- Writing the `byteData` to a new file gives me an image file with empty `metadata/exif`.
- Trying to get the absolute path of the image using the `identifier` parameter from `Asset` object just gives me the path to a cached image with empty `metadata/exif`.
- Found no packages that permits me writing the `metadata/exif` to a new file. All libs I found just allows me reading metadata.
- Tried using `file_picker` package but it doesn't fit my needs unfortunately, since I need more control over the picker UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 7,
    enableCamera: true,
    selectedAssets: images,
    cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
    materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
      actionBarColor: "#C40E3D",
      actionBarTitle: "My App",
      allViewTitle: "All Photos",
      useDetailsView: false,
      selectCircleStrokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
    ),
  );
} on Exception catch (e) {
  error = e.toString();
}

var imageList = resultList;

for (int i =0; i < imageList.length; i++)
var filepicker =
        await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageList[i].identifier);
```

and you can show it like this

```
image.file(File(filepicker[0])),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I already tried that.
It's the second item of things I tried on my question.
This method gives me the path to a cached image with empty `metadata/exif`

Comment: Were you able to fix this, i am trying to get image original name instead of the cached one?